# Вывести меню при клике на иконку в панели задач

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Как с помощью Qt добавить такую панель при клике по иконке на панели задач?

Пробовал использовать **QWinTaskbarButton**, но ничего кроме прогресс-бара добавить не смог.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен класс `QWinJumpList` из того же модуля `Qt Windows Extras`:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwinextras-overview.html#jump-lists

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);


    QWinJumpListItem* winLink = new QWinJumpListItem(QWinJumpListItem::Link);
    winLink->setFilePath("D:\\prog.exe");
    winLink->setArguments(QStringList(QString("arg")));
    winLink->setDescription("Some Description");
    winLink->setIcon(QIcon("D:\\Icon1.ico"));
    winLink->setTitle("Some Text");


    QWinJumpListCategory* myListCat = new QWinJumpListCategory;
    myListCat->setTitle("setTitle");
    myListCat->addItem(winLink);
    myListCat->setVisible(true);


    QWinJumpList mainWinList;
    mainWinList.addCategory(myListCat);
    mainWinList.tasks()->setVisible(true);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Для **QWinJumpListCategory** и **QWinJumpListItem** нужно выделять память динамически, иначе краш при удалении  **QWinJumpList**